# Solution to the Logistic Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> The following is a population model with harvest, N(*t*) at time *t*. Assume that the model for harvest is $\frac{dN}{dt} = r(1-\frac{N}{K})N - hN$ with $r>0$ and $K>0$, and harvest is $h>0$.

I am trying to solve this equation, but I am stuck and I need a push in the right direction.

My attempt:

**(1) Firstly, separate equations:**

$\frac{dN}{rN(1-\frac{N}{K}-hk)} = dt$; then $\int\frac{dN}{rN(1-\frac{N}{K}-hk)} = t$

**(2) Use partial fractions:**

$\int\frac{dN}{rN(1-\frac{N}{K}-hk)} = \int\frac{{AdN}}{N} + \int\frac{BdN}{r(1-\frac{N}{K}-h)}$

**(3) Then I proceeded to go ahead and solve for A:**

$A(r(1-\frac{N}{K})-h) + BN = 1$ which implies that $Ar-Ar\frac{N}{K}-Ah+ BN = 1$. Since we can't find N anywhere in the RHS, we cancel out terms with N, which leaves us with $Ar-Ah=1$.

Then A=  $ \frac{1}{r-h}$

**(4) Plugging A into the equation to solve for B:**

$\frac{1}{r-h}(r-\frac{rN}{k}-h) + BN = 1$, which simplifies to $\frac{kr-rN-kh}{k(r-h)}+ BN= 1.$

**(5) Like in step (3), solve for B:**

$Ar-Ar\frac{N}{K}-Ah+BN=0$
If $A = \frac{1}{r-h}$, then $Ar\frac{N}{K} + BN = 0N$, which says that $\frac{Ar}{k} + B = 0$. Then $B= \frac{-r}{(r-h)k}$

Then I have applied partial fractions with A,B and ended up with the calculation: $\frac{1}{(K-N)^{{k^2}(r-h)}N^{(r-h)}} = Ce^t,$ which is excruciating to solve for N, which led me to doubt my steps.

I think I may have messed up somewhere, but can't point to where the problem is. 
Can someone give me feedback on how to solve logistic equations with harvest? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Let $a=-r/K$ and $b=r-rhK$, then you have 
$$dt = \frac{dN}{aN^{2}+bN} = \frac{dN}{N(aN+b)}$$

You are on the right track, so simplifying notation should help.

Comment: I see. How did you come to decide values of a and b? I see that you chose a and b to be non-N constants, and I am curious as to how you picked them so they produce partial fractions nicely.

Comment: There was nothing special about it. I simply grouped the coefficients of the variable $N$ and called $a$ the coeff of $N^{2}$ and $b$ the coeff of $N^{1}$.